# table view changing address after NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm switching between two View Controller here and experience some behaviour I don't understand.

VC A is hosting a table view which is defined in the storyboard with delegate and data source referencing VC A and the table is referencing VC A as well.

The table view is a property of VC A.

When launching the app everything is fine. The table view is filled by data coming from NSUrl.

This is the log from tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:

```
   2016-07-01 12:53:01.662 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832f022200
   2016-07-01 12:53:01.663 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:0  
   2016-07-01 12:53:01.663 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832f022200  
   2016-07-01 12:53:01.663 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:0  
   2016-07-01 12:53:01.671 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832f022200  
   2016-07-01 12:53:01.671 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:0  
   2016-07-01 12:53:06.743 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832f022200  
   2016-07-01 12:53:06.743 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:25
```

Now if I click on an item in the table view I'm switching to VC B and show the details.

The mystery shows when I switch back to VC A like so:

```
- (IBAction)returnToMain:(id)sender {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsReturnToMain" sender:sender];

            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(updateTargetVC) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void) updateTargetVC{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"detailsReturned" object:_detailDataHolder userInfo:nil];
}
```

object:_detailDataHolder is a pointer to the class which holds the data used for the table view.

Now back in VC A the table view is initialized but when the Notification comes in the address of the table changes as you can see in the log:

```
2016-07-01 12:53:12.659 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832c106000
2016-07-01 12:53:12.659 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:0
2016-07-01 12:53:12.659 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832c106000
2016-07-01 12:53:12.659 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:0
2016-07-01 12:53:12.663 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832c106000
2016-07-01 12:53:12.663 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:0
2016-07-01 12:53:16.662 Loc2[18612:4091131] tbl:0x7f832f022200
2016-07-01 12:53:16.662 Loc2[18612:4091131] count:25
```

VC A receives the Notification as such:

```
-(void)detailsReturned: (NSNotification *) notification{

    [self updateTable];

}
```

I'm stuck here and have no clou what is changing the address of the table view.

Thanks!

Comment: When you perform the segue, it's creating a new element, it's not a "go back" (dismiss, or `popViewControllerAnimated:`). Check with login the address of the VCA to be sure.

Comment: `DetailsReturnToMain` needs to be an unwind segue.

Comment: Larme - I understand that VC A is created and I will get new instances, but the change in the address happens after viewDidload when the VC is already up and running. I'm delaying the Notification with a timer and only after VC A received the Notification and updates the table view the address of the table view is changed ( see timing in the lower log file, it's about 4 sec later)

Comment: Using timers and NSNotification isn't the way to do this. You should use an unwind segue https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html you can get the data from a property of the sending view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the comments:

Sorry, but I think you *don't* understand Larme, ClausM. You do *not* go back with your code unless your segue is an unwind segue. You go "further down" in the VC hierarchy, i.e. you create a new one (which then gets a `viewDidLoad` message, has its own table and all). You have two instances of A in the end, and apparently your logs come from the second one. I assume the way you handle your notification callback results in only A2 logging anything (I think so because you pass `_detailDataHolder` as well with it, I'd need to see how your notification callback works to further judge).

To summarize:
You create an instance A. Clicking on a cell instantiates B, where you do additional stuff that is later needed by A. Then, however, you do not go back to A, but instantiate A2. *This* then gets the data. Obviously it has a new table, along with everything else.

If that is not the case we can't provide further feedback without additional info (i.e. code) from you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Gero and Larme. Unwinding solved it for me.